# Choice of tense to describe continuing status of an object

Tags: grammar, tenses

Hi I am so confused by the English tenses when I try to describe, for example a status change, something happened in the past, just at a point in time, but is still true until now.

Please list those that are grammatically correct and state the meaning you get from these sentences:

1. Ticket #123 opened on 01/01/2014 is closed on 02/02/2014
2. Ticket #123 opened on 01/01/2014 was closed on 02/02/2014
3. Ticket #123 opened on 01/01/2014 has closed on 02/02/2014
4. Ticket #123 opened on 01/01/2014 has been closed on 02/02/2014
5. Ticket #123 opened on 01/01/2014 had closed on 02/02/2014
6. Ticket #123 opened on 01/01/2014 had been closed on 02/02/2014

My personal feeling to these sentences is like

1. The ticket is now closed, but adding "on ..." makes it sound wrong
2. The ticket changed to closed status on 02/02/2014, but not sure the current status
3. I think this is grammatically incorrect
4. Same as 3.
5. I think this is the correct saying
6. Same as 5., but with the additional piece of information telling me that the ticket did not close by itself, someone closed it.

Please correct me.

Comment: My initial problem with this question is that I don't see how a ticket can be opened or closed.

Comment: @tunny It's probably a support ticket in customer service.

Comment: Yeah thanks Ronan, I should have used something more common as example, but that just came to my mind for no reason. May be I was haunted by these customer supports!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your confusion here, I suspect, has to do with the fact that tickets are sometimes spoken of as things that get closed by people ("the ticket was closed" or "the ticket has been closed") and sometimes as things that close of their own accord ("The ticket has closed").

*Ticket #123 opened on 01/01/2014 is closed on 02/02/2014*

"narrative style|historical present".  Two people are looking through data forensically, following the trail of information, and speaking of the past using the present tense, as if they were there, "reenacting" the events as they happen.

*Ticket #123 opened on 01/01/2014 was closed on 02/02/2014*

Simple past.  A discrete action in the past.

*Ticket #123 opened on 01/01/2014 has closed on 02/02/2014*

Ungrammatical, IMO.   It should be either
"was closed on 2/2/2014" OR "has (been) closed" (without the date).

*Ticket #123 opened on 01/01/2014 has been closed on 02/02/2014*

Ungrammatical.  "on 02/02/2014" should not be present.

*Ticket #123 opened on 01/01/2014 had closed on 02/02/2014*

Makes sense only if the ticket was reopened.

*Ticket #123 opened on 01/01/2014 had been closed on 02/02/2014*

Makes sense only if the ticket had been reopened.

ADDENDUM:

Why is this statement ungrammatical?
*Ticket #123 opened on 01/01/2014 has closed on 02/02/2014*

The time-element in a present perfect statement (e.g. "has closed") must be *indefinite*, that is, it must be a form (implicit or explicit) that is analogous to either "recently" or "occasionally|on occasion".

> Are you hungry?
>
> CORRECT: --No, thanks, I've eaten  (I have eaten).
>
> INCORRECT: No, thanks, I've eaten this morning.  (I *ate* this morning).
>
> In the US, we have these shops where you can order coffee prepared in many different ways.
>
> CORRECT: -- Do you think I'm from Mars? I know what a coffee-shop is! I've been to coffee shops before.
>
> INCORRECT: I have been to a coffee shop on 02/02/2014.

Comment: Thank you so much for tackling each of my example. Yes, the use of passive voice or not confuse me a lot, but it seems both are acceptable, I shall not pay too much attention to it then.

Comment: Also, IMO even thought a date is added for "has closed", we can make it correct by saying "has closed since 02/02/2014", right?

Comment: Has *been* closed since 02/02/2014.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who works in a support ticket environment and provides support for usage of a ticketing system, the only sentence that makes sense *in context* is 2. And all of the sentences are incorrect because the ticket *was* opened.

This is the normal way that would be stated and understood:

> Ticket #123 was opened on 01/01/2014 and was closed on 02/02/2014.

Even if one doesn't know what the current status is, in a ticketing system, if the status was closed, it's still closed. It will always be understood as closed unless explicitly stated as re-opened or opened again. Further, it will be assumed that the person making the statement will be reporting the current state of the ticket and the date of state change unless asked for a specifically different state:

> When was the last time the state was changed to *Awaiting Customer*?

All recorded ticket state changes are in the past tense.

Comment: I love how you relate my imaginary example to real world ticketing system. It is really useful to learn how stuff works from the field people. My thanks to you.